# I am getting a moongose error whitle adding a second user to db. ERROR CODE 110000

Tags: reactjs

I am working with clerk webhooks I am getting some issues.

This is my clerk webhook route code

```
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { createUser, deleteUser, updateUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";
import { clerkClient } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // You can find this in the Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the webhook
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
    );
  }

  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
    return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json();
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  let evt: WebhookEvent;

  // Verify the payload with the headers
  try {
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svix_id,
      "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
      "svix-signature": svix_signature,
    }) as WebhookEvent;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
    return new Response("Error occured", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the ID and type
  const { id } = evt.data!;
  const eventType = evt.type;

  if (eventType === "user.created") {
    const { id, email_addresses, username, first_name, last_name, image_url } =
      evt?.data!;
    console.log("id from route.ts", evt.data.id);
    const user = {
      clerkId: id,
      email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
      username: username!,
      firstName: first_name,
      lastName: last_name,
      photo: image_url,
    };

    const newUser = await createUser(user);

    if (newUser) {
      await clerkClient.users.updateUserMetadata(evt?.data?.id, {
        publicMetadata: {
          userId: newUser._id,
        },
      });
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: newUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.updated") {
    const { id, image_url, first_name, last_name, username } = evt.data;

    const user = {
      firstName: first_name,
      lastName: last_name,
      username: username!,
      photo: image_url,
    };

    const updatedUser = await updateUser(id, user);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: updatedUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.deleted") {
    const { id } = evt.data;

    const deletedUser = await deleteUser(id!);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: deletedUser });
  }

  return new Response("", { status: 200 });
}
```

this is my user model

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
    clerkId: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    photo: {type: String, required: true},
})

const User = models.User || model("User", userSchema)

export default User
```

whenever i try to create a new user in clerk first user gets saved in the db and every thing works fine but when i create a second user the i get this error from mongoose

```
⨯ Error: {"index":0,"code":11000,"keyPattern":{"clerkID":1},"keyValue":{"clerkID":null}}
    at o (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/webhook/clerk/route.js:1:7505)
    at y (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/webhook/clerk/route.js:1:2636)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async O (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/webhook/clerk/route.js:1:4471)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:41960
```

these are my server logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRfWO.png)

you can clearly see that above the clerkid is not null but i am still getting this error. please help i am stuck at this for a while.

i am getting this error for a while.